# Multithread socket server and multiple ports to close

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am making an java application, and my need is that there are multiple clients and every client has to connect to different port or on same port (User Choice). So I use multithreading and make sockets on different ports to listen different clients. My problem is 
1. SocketException when client is connected 
2. the data between client and server is not send/recieved

Server Code

```
package crawl_manager;


import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;



/**
 *
 * @author Harjinder
 */
public class crawler_server extends Thread {

 url_dispacher udis;
 db_Connection db;

protected int          serverPort   = 8080;
protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
protected boolean      isStopped    = false;
protected Thread       runningThread= null;


public crawler_server(int port){
    this.serverPort = port;
}

public crawler_server() throws IOException, SQLException
  {
     db =new db_Connection();


  }   



 @SuppressWarnings("CallToThreadStopSuspendOrResumeManager")
      public void startCrawler(int port) throws SQLException, IOException
  {
   crawler_server server = new crawler_server(port);
 new Thread(server).start();

 try {
Thread.sleep(2000 * 1000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
System.out.println(e);
 }
System.out.println("Stopping Server");
 server.stopabc();


  }


      private void openServerSocket() {
    try {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 8080", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void run(){
    synchronized(this){
        this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
    openServerSocket();
    while(! isStopped()){
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(isStopped()) {
                System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
                return;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Error accepting client connection", e);
        }
        new Thread(
            new WorkerRunnable(
                clientSocket, "Multithreaded Server")
        ).start();
    }
    System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
}


private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
    return this.isStopped;
}


     public synchronized void stopabc(){
    this.isStopped = true;
    try {
        this.serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
    }
}

  }
```

**WorkerRunnable code**

```
package crawl_manager;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable{

protected Socket clientSocket = null;
protected String serverText   = null;

public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, String serverText) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.serverText   = serverText;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        long time;
        try (
                InputStream input = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream()



                ) {
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            output.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nWorkerRunnable: " +this.serverText + " - " + time + "").getBytes());
            System.out.println(input.read()+"input he server ka");

        }

        System.out.println("Request processed: " + time);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

**Client Code**

```
package crawler_client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Crawler_client {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 db_Connection db;

 public Crawler_client()
  {

this.db = new db_Connection();
 }

/**
 *
 * @param sentence
 * @throws SQLException
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
 public void send(String sentence) throws SQLException, IOException
{  
 String ip = null;
     int port = 0;
     System.out.println(sentence);
     Socket clientSocket = null; 
 DataOutputStream os = null;
 BufferedReader is = null;

     String sql = "Select * from conn_settings where server='crawl_manager' ";
     ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);
     if(rs.next()){
         port=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("port"));
         ip=(rs.getString("ip"));

     }
     else{
     }
       try
        {
            clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
            os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
   }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + ip);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + ip);
        }

    // If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data
    // to the socket we have opened a connection to on the given port

        if (clientSocket == null || os == null || is == null)
        {
            System.err.println( "Something is wrong. One variable is null." );
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            while ( true )
            {
                System.out.print( "Enter an integer (0 to stop connection, -1 to stop server): " );
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String keyboardInput = br.readLine();
                os.writeBytes( keyboardInput + "\n" );

                int n = Integer.parseInt( keyboardInput );
                if ( n == 0 || n == -1 ) {
                break;
            }

            String responseLine = is.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server returns its square as: " + responseLine);
        }

        // clean up:
        // close the output stream
        // close the input stream
        // close the socket

    os.close();
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();  
      }
      catch (UnknownHostException e)
      {
          System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
          System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
      }
   }          

}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace, and indicate which of these lines the exception is thrown from. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Your WorkerRunnable will process only one message and exit